# Remove strip background keep panel border

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following type of plot and want to keep each strip text above the individual facet box as a "title" of sorts yet not have the default grey background and black border around the `strip.background`.  I color it white which is close to what I want but would like the bottom edge of the `strip.background` or top edge of `panel.border` to be black.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~carb, ncol = 3) + theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you set `element_blank()` for `strip.background` and keep `element_rect(colour="black", fill = NA)` for `panel.border` then top edge of `panel.border` will be black.
As pointed out by @adrien, for `panel.background` fill should be set to NA to avoid covering of points (already set as default for `theme_bw()`).

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~carb, ncol = 3) + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: As adrien points out below, to do this you must use `panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA)`. I believe this became the case in a version of ggplot after this answer was originally posted.

Comment: @GMSL You are right. My solution works because this is the default for `theme_bw()`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 12):

Setting `panel.border` might cover your graph unless you also add `fill=NA` to `panel.border` :

```
theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black"))
```

One can also use:

```
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"))
```

[source](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html) (section "Panel Attributes")

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
 strip.background = element_rect(colour=NA, fill=NA),
 panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"))
```