# Edit distance between the facet / strip and the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

For example,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(cols = vars(drv))
```

[image]
How can I change the distance between the strip and the main plot? (For example, create a gap between the strip and the main plot.)
But I don't need to change the strip size (different from this [edit strip size ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428344/edit-strip-size-ggplot2)).

Comment: I think you should specify `theme(strip.background =...)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185754/remove-strip-background-keep-panel-border

Comment: @atsyplenkov I need to create a gap between the strip and the main plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution

```
theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

Answer (score 4):

There can be multiple solutions to this problem.

#### `geom_hline`

A hacky one is to add a line (probably white, but it depends on your theme) on top of the plot. We can do this using `geom_hline` (or `geom_vline` if your facets are in rows). This creates an illusion of distance.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(drv)) +
  # Add white line on top (Inf) of the plot (ie, betweem plot and facet)
  geom_hline(yintercept = Inf, color = "white", size = 4) +
  labs(title = "geom_hline")
```

---

#### `strip.background`

Another solution (as suggested by @atsyplenkov) is to use `theme(strip.background = ...)`. There you can specify color of the border. However, this is not a perfect as it cuts border from all the directions (there might be a way to improve this).

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(drv)) +
  # Increase size of the border
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "white", size = 3)) +
  labs(title = "strip.background")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another yet simple option is to create "invisible" strips first and then adjust the text vertically:

```
    + theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "white", fill = "white"),
            strip.text.x = element_text(vjust = 5)
```

In my case, I used it to reduce space between strip text and plot. But it should work vice versa.